# How to solve issues (errors)in rails locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

encountered with no method error . how to solve it and check it?

I tried rails console and couldn't able to call the method .

```
class dashboardcontroller
def get_meta_data
    require 'link_thumbnailer'
    begin
    object = LinkThumbnailer.generate(params[:url])
    rescue StandardError
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: { title: object.title, image: object.images.first.src.to_s, description: object.description,
                       url: object.url, status: 200 }
```

Comment: also share your code in the question

Comment: please tell step by step sir. how to call a method in console.and how to check the solved error.    got no method error for "first".

Comment: No method error for "first" means there are no images for object. There is a possibility of LinkThumbnailer  throwing a error. Remove the rescue StandardError and check if the code is raising error. Or make use of pry gem for debugging. Basically check why images are not present for the newly created object.

Comment: sorry sir ..no method error for "title" . i have used binding.pry in code...but while starting the server..there is no stopping.  how to use console-pry to debug .

Comment: checkout the debugging tutorial https://www.jackkinsella.ie/articles/debugging-rails-with-pry-debugger

Comment: sir how to reporduce the issue locally and test it...

Answer (score 0):

You can do couple of things here:

- Move your `require` file on top in the controller.
- Use rescue with your controller method `get_meta_data`
- Check your `LinkThumbnailer` class if its actually generating or not.
- Then use `puts` to show actually what is it that you actually assigning in `object`
- After all of this you must confirm if `object` has all the attributes you are using while rendering json.